# Chamar uma função com o nome variável

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que deverá ser chamada, porém o nome dela é montado dinamicamente, baseado em uma variável que virá como parâmetro.

Seguem as funções como exemplo. A primeira é chamada e pega o nome do programa.
Chama a segunda passando o nome, que deverá chamar a terceira caso seja necessário.

```
// Primeira
function CarregarPrograma(){
   // Códigos.....
   sPrg = $("div#id_prg").attr("data-programa");
   FuncaoEspecifica(sPrg);
}

// Segunda
function FuncaoEspecifica(prg){
   if ($("div#" + prg).attr("data-inicio") == "1"){
      Inicio_ (valor que vier no parãmetro) ;
   }
}

// Terceira que deve ser chamada da segunda.
function Inicio_admcad00002(){
    // Código a ser executado...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `window["Nome_função"](argumentos)`, assim:

```
window["Inicio_" + (valor que vier no parametro)]();
```

Ou seja

```
window["Inicio_" + prg]();
```

Onde prg é a variável que virá como parâmetro.

Evite usar `eval`, não é recomendado

Comment: Apaguei a minha resposta porque a sua é melhor.

Comment: Obrigado Estevao, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de passar o nome da função, passe sua referência. Por exemplo,

```
const minhaFuncao = () => console.log('minhaFuncao foi executada!');
const chamarQualquerFuncao = (funcaoASerChamada) => funcaoASerChamada();

chamarQualquerFuncao(minhaFuncao); // log: minhaFuncao foi executada!
```

Alguns conselhos:

- Não use `window` para armazenar dados da aplicação.
- Não defina os nomes das funções dinamicamente.
- Não chame as funções usando strings.
- Não use `eval()`.